# Adding a 2nd user for Apache2 www/html folder

Tags: php, apache2, raspberry-pi3

I have an Apache2 site set up on a RPI3 with basic authentication. It worked great since I am really the only user. I am now using IFTTT to automate a few items via webhooks to use a GET request to a couple .php files I have in the www/html folder. This works just fine, but where I have the issue is having to set the webhook with my username: password since I have an authenticated site. I have been using a dynamic dns server for this access my site via username:password@mysite:80/file.php. Is there a way to create a separate folder with a username and password that can only access that folder and not the entire www/html directory? I don't like the fact that my main login is sent by IFTTT. If possible I would like it to be NEWUSER:PASSWORD@mysite:80/limited/file.php.

I have tried creating a this folder and adding its access to the apache2.conf, 000sites-enabled. I have also tried adding its own .htaccess and .htpasswd file in the "limited" folder with a different user.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more concrete what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work by removing the entries for the sub directory "limited" folder from the Apache2.config and 000sites-enabled. I also just kept the 2 files for .htpasswd and .htaccess in the "limited" folder.

.htpasswd :

User:$sjjnuinusencryptedpasswordijkmi22993

.htaccess :

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/limited/.htpasswd

Hope this helps someone.